# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (BAD REQUEST)-React

Tags: reactjs

I am Useding Axios to for to make a request, the code work so well when testing it with postman, but when I try runing the code on the client side it will fail with the 127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth/register:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (BAD REQUEST)

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

function setUserObject(user) {
  if (!user) {
    return null;
  }
  return {
    username: user.username,
    id: user.id,
    first_name: user.first_name,
  };
}

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth";
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [token, setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem("token"));
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [isServerError, setIsServerError] = useState(false);

  const registerUser = async (registerData) => {
    try {
      const finalData = {
        username: registerData.username,
        password: registerData.password,
        email: registerData.email,
        first_name: registerData.firstName,
        last_name: registerData.lastName,
        address: registerData.address,
        phone: registerData.phone,

      };
      const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/register`, finalData);
      if (response.status === 201) {
        console.log("Successful registration! Log in to access token");
        setIsServerError(false);
        navigate("/login");
      } else {
        setIsServerError(true);
        console.log("Registration failed.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setIsServerError(true);
      console.error("An error occurred during registration:", error.response.data);
    }
  };

  const loginUser = async (loginData) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/login`, loginData);
      if (response && response.status === 200 && response.data && response.data.access) {
        const accessToken = response.data.access;
        localStorage.setItem("token", accessToken);
        setToken(accessToken);
        const loggedInUser = jwtDecode(accessToken);
        setUser(setUserObject(loggedInUser));
        setIsServerError(false);
        navigate("/");
      } else {
        navigate("/register");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error logging in:", error);
      setIsServerError(true);
      navigate("/register");
    }
  };

  const logoutUser = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    setUser(null);
    setToken(null);
    navigate("/");
  };

  const contextData = {
    user,
    token,
    loginUser,
    logoutUser,
    registerUser,
    isServerError,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextData}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContext`




import React, { useContext, useEffect} from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthContext from "../../context/AuthContext";
import useCustomForm from "../../hooks/useCustomForm";

const RegisterPage = () => {
  const { registerUser, isServerError } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const [formData, handleInputChange, handleSubmit, reset] = useCustomForm(
    {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      username: "",
      email: "",
      address: "",
      phone_number: ""
    },
    registerUser
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isServerError) {
      reset();
    }
  }, [isServerError, reset]);

  return (
    <div className="lo-container">
      <div className="logbanner"></div>
      <div className="login-form">
        <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h1>New member setup an account</h1>
          <div className="form-row"></div>
          <label className="form-label">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="firstName"
              value={formData.firstName || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="First Name"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <label className="form-label">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="lastName"
              value={formData.lastName || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Last Name"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <label className="form-label">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="username"
              value={formData.username || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Username"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <label className="form-label">
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              value={formData.password || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Password"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <label className="form-label">
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              value={formData.email || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Email"
              required
              
            />
          </label>
          <label className="form-label">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="address"
              value={formData.address || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Address"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <label className="form-label">
            <input
              type="tel"
              name="phone_number"
              value={formData.phone_number || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              maxLength="200"
              placeholder="Phone Number"
              required
            />
          </label>
          {isServerError ? (
            <p className="error">Registration failed, please try again.</p>
          ) : null}
          <button className="login-btn">Register!</button>
          <div className="divider">
            <span className="divider-text">or</span>
          </div>
          <p>Already have an account?</p>
          <Link to="/login" className="sign-up-btn">
            Login
          </Link>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RegisterPage;



import React, { useContext, useEffect} from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthContext from "../../context/AuthContext";
import useCustomForm from "../../hooks/useCustomForm";

const RegisterPage = () => {
  const { registerUser, isServerError } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const [formData, handleInputChange, handleSubmit, reset] = useCustomForm(
    {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      username: "",
      email: "",
      address: "",
      phone_number: ""
    },
    registerUser
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isServerError) {
      reset();
    }
  }, [isServerError, reset]);

  return (
    <div className="lo-container">
      <div className="logbanner"></div>
      <div className="login-form">
        <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h1>New member setup an account</h1>
          <div className="form-row"></div>
          <label className="form-label">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="firstName"
              value={formData.firstName || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="First Name"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <label className="form-label">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="lastName"
              value={formData.lastName || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Last Name"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <label className="form-label">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="username"
              value={formData.username || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Username"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <label className="form-label">
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              value={formData.password || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Password"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <label className="form-label">
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              value={formData.email || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Email"
              required
              
            />
          </label>
          <label className="form-label">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="address"
              value={formData.address || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Address"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <label className="form-label">
            <input
              type="tel"
              name="phone_number"
              value={formData.phone_number || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              maxLength="200"
              placeholder="Phone Number"
              required
            />
          </label>
          {isServerError ? (
            <p className="error">Registration failed, please try again.</p>
          ) : null}
          <button className="login-btn">Register!</button>
          <div className="divider">
            <span className="divider-text">or</span>
          </div>
          <p>Already have an account?</p>
          <Link to="/login" className="sign-up-btn">
            Login
          </Link>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RegisterPage;
```

I want to be able to register and login a user, Using the postman API to the test the request it work so well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should debug this on server side to understand exactly which field is sending unexpected data.
That being said, I see potential 2 problems which might cause 400 error here

1. In `formData` you have a field named `phone_number` but before sending it to server, you are reading it from `phone` which might cause bad data error if `phone` is undefined and is required by server.
2. You do not have a field called `password` declared in your formData so that might cause an issue if password is not sent to the server.

Comment: Thank you so much, after editing `formData` from phone to phone_number and adding the password field,  I was able to register a user from the client side but  I got the error below when try to login the user

 `login:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received`   and



`register:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received`

Comment: Try logging in in Incognito mode. You can post a snippet here with the issue if it still persists. It however looks like an unrelated issue. Please accept the answer if original issue is resolved.

Comment: alright, thank you. When I tried logging in Incognito mode I got no error but a warning message and navigated to the register page
`[DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes (suggested: "current-password"):  <input type=​"password" name=​"password" placeholder=​"Password" required value>​`

Comment: I believe it is simply expecting the prop ```autocomplete``` to be declared on password ```input``` tag. You can refer this article for more information and how to use it https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/input-elements-should-have-autocomplete-attributes

Comment: When I trying login in a user I will be navigated to the register page, so I debug the AuthContext.js file and I find out that data from the database is not being fetched. So I change the code (attach code) 
and  I am having `react-dom.development.js:26923 Uncaught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON`

Comment: `export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth";
  const userToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));
  const decodedUser = userToken ? jwtDecode(userToken) : null;
  const [token, setToken] = useState(userToken);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(setUserObject(decodedUser));
  const [isServerError, setIsServerError] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();`

Comment: `const loginUser = async (loginData) => {
    try {
      let response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/login`, loginData);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(response.data.access));
        setToken(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token")));
        let loggedInUser = jwtDecode(response.data.access);
        setUser(setUserObject(loggedInUser));
        setIsServerError(false);
        navigate("/");
      } else {
        navigate("/register");
      }`

Comment: The code is difficult to understand in the comment. Please provide a link to the snippet where issue can be replicated.

Comment: ok thanks, here is the code snippet 
https://snipit.io/public/snippets/80843

Comment: It is most probably not able to get ```response.data.access``` which you are setting inside ```loginUser``` and hence it is going to the catch block navigating to ```register``` route. You need to debug your code and see what response is returned by the ```login api```.

Comment: Thank you so much, when I debug it I got this error `content-script.js:15 Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received`